# Google Analytics 4 (gtag.js): recommended/custom events do not show in realtime or in reports, only in debug mode

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs3, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I am running Vue 3 + Nuxt, and running Google Analytics 4 (GA4) using [Nuxt gtag.js module](https://github.com/johannschopplich/nuxt-gtag).

GA4 is correctly reporting all the default events, such as `page_view`, `scroll`, and `click`. However, when I try to send a recommended event, namely `search`, I run into several issues.

Firstly, it is not showing up in the reports. However, I have read elsewhere that it may take up to 12 - 24 to do this. The bigger issue that it is also not showing up in the realtime reports.

Secondly, the strange thing is that the `search` event does show up when `debug_mode` is enabled. It shows up both in the debug view (under Admin), as well as in the realtime view.

```js
  gtag("event", "search", {
    search_term: mySearchTerm,
  });
```

Could it be the case that I need to set up this event somewhere in the GA4 dashboard, or will GA4 automatically do this once the event is received?
Any suggestions/ideas what could be causing this?

I have tried viewing network traffic, and as such the data does get added to the `window.dataLayer`  array, and the data is sent occasionally to the GA4.